# Can I lazily initialize multiple variables in one class, or do I need to create a class for each?

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I have about 10 variables in a utility class library that is used by multiple applications.  Each one loads data from a database and as I've added variables, the startup delay is getting too long, so I figured it's time to refactor and lazily initialize all the variables.  Here is an example:

```
public static readonly StringCollection BananaTypes = GetBananaTypes();
public static readonly StringCollection FlowerTypes = GetFlowerTypes();
// etc
```

changes to:

```
private static StringCollection privateBananaTypes;
public static StringCollection BananaTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (privateBananaTypes == null)
        {
            lock (privateBananaTypes)
            {
                if (privateBananaTypes == null)
                {
                    privateBananaTypes = GetBananaTypesCollection();
                }
            }
        }
        return privateBananaTypes;
    }
}
private static StringCollection privateFlowerTypes;
public static StringCollection FlowerTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (privateFlowerTypes == null)
        {
            lock (privateFlowerTypes)
            {
                if (privateFlowerTypes == null)
                {
                    privateFlowerTypes = GetFlowerTypeCollection();
                }
            }
        }
        return privateFlowerTypes;
    }
}
```

All the Get... are static methods in the containing class.  When I go to use one of the StringCollections I get an ArgumentNullException.

Does each variable have to be placed in a separate class?  Can I initialize each separate variable in this one class lazily?  If so how do I go that?  Right now I think the first time I use the class all the variables would have to be initialized, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an `ArgumentNullException` because you cannot `lock` on a null object.  You would need to create a different object (which is always non-null) to make your code work.  (Aside from that, there is nothing wrong with initializing multiple lazy variables in a single class.)

Alternatively, .NET 4.0 provides the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class for integrated, thread-safe lazy initialization.  The code you wrote above could be rewritten as follows:

```
private static Lazy<StringCollection> privateBananaTypes = new Lazy<StringCollection>(GetBananaTypesCollection);
public static StringCollection BananaTypes
{
    get { return privateBananaTypes.Value; }
}

private static Lazy<StringCollection> privateFlowerTypes = new Lazy<StringCollection>(GetFlowerTypesCollection);
public static StringCollection FlowerTypes
{
    get { return privateFlowerTypes.Value; }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation and like the alternative solution even better.  I was able to update my code to use another object that existed to lock and then scraped that and switched to using the Lazy keyword example above.